# j2me importing external jar: what classpath?

Tags: java, java-me, classpath

I want to import some external jar file in a j2me project (not including it into final build). So I would copy my jar and external jar on a device, run my jar and use classes from this jar. (like import ext_pack.ext_class; and then use it like ext.class.ext_method()). What classpath should I write and where should I put my jars on device?

Comment: You can import external jar file in your project and create single jar file

Comment: I know, but I need exactly 2 files

Comment: and what do you mean by "exactly 2 files" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class loading is not generally available in most J2ME profiles (not in the [CLDC 1.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/cldc1.1/jsr139/index.html) spec). You can't do this.

Comment: That's not what I meant. Not actually loading class, but importing it and then using... I edited my post

Comment: As far as I can recall you can not have multiple jar files in a deployed j2me project.